# mongodb sql in statement equivalent

Tags: java, mongodb

I have found two ways of doing an equivalent of SQL in statement in mongodb.
One way would be something like:

```
BasicDBObject inQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(2);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
inQuery.put("employeeId", new BasicDBObject("$in", list));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(inQuery);
```

And the other one, with a filter, would be something like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("coll_name")
            .find(in("field_name", values))
```

My questions are:

- Which way is better?
- Is it better to use filters? What about the performance between doing the query is the first way against using a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise and semantically there is no difference.

Both result in the same command being sent to the database. The [`Filters.in(field, values)`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Iterable-) method is just an alternative syntax for `new BasicDBObject(field, new BasicDBObject("$in", values))`.

Which one you consider better from a code-stylistic point of view is your personal preference.